# Array instead of a single item in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

This is giving me an array with two items though the query output should be a single cell, it's possibly obvious, but not to a beginner like me

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

function dbFetch($db,$query)
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

$query = " 
SELECT
Name
FROM Players WHERE PlayerID='21'"; 
$rows = dbFetch($db,$query);
var_dump($rows);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "PLAYERNAME" [0]=> string(6) "PLAYERNAME" }
```

It's repeating the output first as associate and secondly as a numeric.

Comment: You're getting both an associative and a numeric index. Just use one with `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) instead. It will return the first column from the first record.

```
function dbFetch($db,$query)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    return $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
}
```

Also, I'd be willing to bet you aren't searching for "21" but rather a variable. In that case you'd be much better off using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), and modifying your code like so:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
function dbFetch($db,$query,$params=[])
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute($params); 
    return $stmt->fetch();
}

$query = " 
SELECT
Name
FROM Players WHERE PlayerID=?";
$params = array("your user id"); 
$rows = dbFetch($db,$query,$params);
var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: Would you have an insight into why it creates two items?

Comment: @denski [the default fetch_style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) is to fetch both numeric and associative. `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`

Comment: Hey, I am using prepared statements, just wanted to keep this as light as possible. many thanks.

Comment: so in a function `$params=[ ]` makes the default `[ ]` if `$params` has no value? cool!

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to the fetch style.

As per php manual:

> public mixed PDOStatement::fetch ([ int $fetch_style [, int
>   $cursor_orientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT [, int $cursor_offset = 0
>   ]]] ) Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement
>   object. The fetch_style parameter determines how PDO returns the row.
>
> fetch_style Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller.
>   This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to
>   value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to
>   PDO::FETCH_BOTH).
>
> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOUND: returns TRUE and assigns the values of the columns
>   in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were bound with
>   the PDOStatement::bindColumn() method
>
> PDO::FETCH_CLASS: returns a new instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>   class, and calling the constructor afterwards, unless
>   PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE is also given. If fetch_style includes
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g. PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE)
>   then the name of the class is determined from a value of the first
>   column.
>
> PDO::FETCH_INTO: updates an existing instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class
>
> PDO::FETCH_LAZY: combines PDO::FETCH_BOTH and PDO::FETCH_OBJ, creating
>   the object variable names as they are accessed
>
> PDO::FETCH_NAMED: returns an array with the same form as
>   PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, except that if there are multiple columns with the
>   same name, the value referred to by that key will be an array of all
>   the values in the row that had that column name
>
> PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned
>   in your result set, starting at column 0
>
> PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that
>   correspond to the column names returned in your result set
>
> PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE: when used with PDO::FETCH_CLASS, the
>   constructor of the class is called before the properties are assigned
>   from the respective column values.